# Pig script scheduled by crontab not giving result

Tags: hadoop, cron, apache-pig, bigdata

I have pig script which when I run from pig(map reduce mode) gives proper result but when I schedule from crontab does not store output as per the script.

Pig script is,

```
a1 = load '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/id' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,name:chararray,desig:chararray); 
a2 = load '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/trips' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,place:chararray,no_trips:int); 
j = join a1 by id,a2 by id;
g = group j by(a1::id,a1::name,a1::desig);`  
`su = foreach g generate group,SUM(j.a2::no_trips) as tripsum; 
ord = order su by tripsum desc; 
f2 = foreach ord generate $0.$0,$0.$1,$0.$2,$1; 
store f2 into '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/results/trip_output' using PigStorage(' ');
```

Crontab is,

```
[training@localhost ~]$ crontab -l
40 3 * * * /home/training/Abhijit_Local/trip_crontab.pig
```

Please Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crontab is attempting to treat the Pig script as an executable file and run it directly.  Instead, you will likely need to pass it through the `pig` command explicitly, as described in the Apache Pig documentation on [Batch Mode](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html#batch-mode).  You may also find it helpful to redirect stdout and stderr output to a log file somewhere in case you need to troubleshoot failures.

```
40 3 * * * pig /home/training/Abhijit_Local/trip_crontab.pig 2>&1 > /some/path/to/logfile
```

Depending on `PATH` environment variable settings, you might find that it's necessary to specify the absolute path to the `pig` command.

```
40 3 * * * /full/path/pig /home/training/Abhijit_Local/trip_crontab.pig 2>&1 > /some/path/to/logfile
```

Comment: Dear Chris thank you for your answer but please elaborate what is PATH settings where will I get absolute path.

Comment: I was referring to the `PATH` environment variable that is used to search for executable files.  If the user who owns this crontab already has the `pig` executable on the `PATH`, then you won't need an absolute path.  If the user does not have `pig` on the `PATH`, then you'll either need to add it to the `PATH` or use an absolute path.  BTW, I also edited the answer to add some information about redirecting output to a log file.

Comment: Dear Chris really thank you for your guidance,my crontab is working now.

Comment: @user8167344, I'm glad to hear it helped!